# discord.js bot to tag random user in server

Tags: random, discord, discord.js

I want to include a '-random' command that will tag random member of a server. I have found the following code:

```
if(command === 'random'){
              
        let randomUser = message.guild.members.cache.random().user;
        message.channel.send('<@'+randomUser+'>');
    }
```

It works but it will only tag me, the bot itself, or someone else if that person recently wrote in the channel. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch all the members first, then call `random()` on the returning collection.

```js
if (command == 'random') {
   message.guild.members.fetch()
      .then(allMembers => {
         const member = allMembers.random();
         message.channel.send(member.toString());
      })
      .catch(console.error);
}
```

Ensure you have the GuildMember's intent enabled for fetching to work.

Comment: thanks, this helped me a lot, as i am a js beginner and do this as a hobby.

Comment: If this solved your issue use the checkmark to the left of my answer to indicate the answer to future users with the same question

Answer (score 0):

To get all the members in a guild, you would have to enable a privileged intent before `client.login(token)`: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents

Make sure you enable the intent in your Discord Developer bot dashboard too: https://discord.com/developers/applications

Comment: thank you, really helped, i dont know why but i get really lost in the documentation